# packaging with webpack when a node_module imports 'fs'

Tags: node.js, webpack, fs

I'm building an isomorphic webapp and have a node_module that is being used both on the server and client.

On the server, a we package we are using imports `fs` but in the browser uses `FileReader`

The packages is included as a node module.

In my webpack, I have included

```
  node: {
        fs: 'empty'
    },
```

but still get an error in the browser saying `cannot find module 'fs'`

I've also tried in webpack
`exclude: /node_modules|fs/`

how can I use this package and have webpack mock or ignore the fs module?